# Format specific date in Apex as dd/mm/yyyy - illegal assignment from string to date

Tags: apex

I tried to find an existing question/answer for my problem, but didn't see anything so I'm trying to format a date in apex as "mm/dd/yyyy", but get the error: "Illegal assignment from String to Date"   My code is below.

```
for( Contact__c contacts : contactrecords ) {
   Candidates__c cands = new Candidate__c();
   cands.Start_Date__c = contacts.Start_Date__c.format('mm/dd/yyyy');
}
```

Basically I'm trying to set the start date field equal to the other start date field, but format is as "mm/dd/yyyy'.  I understand why the error happens, it seems `format()` method returns a string, but don't have a solution to achieve what I want.

Comment: `date.format()` return type is string

Comment: don't format the date, instead directly assign `cands.Start_Date__c = contacts.Start_Date__c;`

Comment: I don't want the time portion of the date, with what you suggested it will give me the time portion and no control over the format of the date.  I want to control the format of the state when i do the assignment @Ratan

Comment: if you just want the date value use `date()` of [datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) class.If you don't want time portion you can not save it again in datetime type field because that will always give you time portion.

Comment: @user1669296 Then I suggest change the `cands.Start_Date__c` dataType to text since you just want to display formatted date text.

Comment: one more way could be to parse the formatted date string into `Date`. In that case type of  `cands.Start_Date__c` would be `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular way by which you can make certain dates to appear in different format(Date and DateTime data types). Date formats are decided by locale setting of current user and all dates appear in same format as set by locale setting.

To change locale setting visit user record and change locale. For example for locale English (united states) date format would be mm-dd-yyyy.